# Power Query: How to update column values in a table?

Tags: powerquery

Need your help with following problem:

I have a query with an Excel table as a source.
This table has several **user-input** columns, which are now required to be multiplied by a coefficient from another column in this table. Column names should be retained.

Example:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromColumns({{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {null, 0.5}}, {"Clmn1", "Clmn2", "ClmnMultiplier"})
in
    Source
```

Is there any way to **update** their values like that:

```
row[Clmn1] = row[Clmn1] * IsNull(Row[ClmnMultiplier],1)
row[Clmn2] = row[Clmn2] * IsNull(Row[ClmnMultiplier],1)
```

or even better by applying a logic for a list of columns.

Sure I can do it by creating new columns, one by one, but I find this both not elegant and not productive.

Can anyone give me an advice on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Alternative solution

```
let
    colNames = {"Clmn1", "Clmn2", "ClmnMultiplier"},
    Source = Table.FromColumns({{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {null, 0.5}}, colNames),
    transformRows = Table.TransformRows(Source, each Record.TransformFields(_, {
        {"Clmn1", (f)=>[Clmn1]*(if [ClmnMultiplier] is null then 1 else [ClmnMultiplier])},
        {"Clmn2", (f)=>[Clmn2]*(if [ClmnMultiplier] is null then 1 else [ClmnMultiplier])}
    }))
in
    Table.FromList(transformRows, Record.ToList, colNames)
```

By the way, you may precalculate
`null_1=(if [ClmnMultiplier] is null then 1 else [ClmnMultiplier])`
outside of function (in each row) and use it like this:

```
...
{"Clmn1", (f)=>[Clmn1]*null_1},
{"Clmn2", (f)=>[Clmn2]*null_1}
...
```

in order to not to calculate it twice

Comment: Well, yes, precalculating is good option and cleaner technique. 
You don't even need a function then: 
{"Clmn1", each [Clmn1]*null_1},

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to the problem.

It is done with `Table.TransformRows` function.
The obvious solution was to use `Table.TransformColumns`, but it turned out that you cannot reference the current row from it. Some search pointed to this solution:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromColumns({{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {null, 0.5}}, {"Clmn1", "Clmn2", "ClmnMultiplier"}),
    Transf = Table.FromRecords(
                Table.TransformRows(Source, 
                    (r) => Record.TransformFields(r,
                            {
                                {"Clmn1", each if r[ClmnMultiplier] <> null then _ * r[ClmnMultiplier] else _}, 
                                {"Clmn2", each if r[ClmnMultiplier] <> null then _ * r[ClmnMultiplier] else _}
                            })
                )
            )
in
    Transf
```

Many thanks to [LoganTheSnowEater](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3316417/loganthesnoweater) and his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548135/power-query-transform-a-column-based-on-another-column)