# Changing one value of row to column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am working on a Power BI report. There are two dimensions `DimWorkedClass` and `DimWorkedService`. (The above snippet is obtained by exporting matrix values to csv.)

The requirement is to transform only the `Worked Service` `Text5` into the `Worked Class` of `Text5` as opposed to `A` (which is the current value).

It can be transformed at the backend, but is there any way to do it in Power BI?

[image: Please see the image here]

Comment: So in this example, you want to replace `A` with `text5` only in the highlighted row?

Comment: Yea, meaning I want the value under Worked Class  to be reflected as "text5" wherever there is Worked Service of "text5"

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is trickier than it might appear, but it looks like this question has already been answered here:

[Power Query Transform a Column based on Another Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548135/power-query-transform-a-column-based-on-another-column)

In your case, the M code would look something like this:

```
= Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(#"[Source or Previous Step Here]",
      (here) => Record.TransformFields(here, {"Worked Class",
          each if here[Worked Service] = "text5" then "text5" else here[Worked Class]})))
```

(In the above, `here` represents the current row.)

Another answer points out a slightly cleaner way of doing this:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"[Source or Previous Step Here]",
      each [Worked Class],
      each if [Worked Service] = "text5" then "text5" else [Worked Class],
      Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Worked Class"})
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexis. May I know what source refers to in "[Source or Previous Step Here]" ?

Comment: The Source is where your data table comes from and is typically the first step in the query.